# VBS script random and switches

Tags: random, vbscript, wsh

In the program below r is initialized as a rounded random number and the user is prompted to guess. If the user guesses correctly there is one prompt Else there is another prompt. The code looks right but when ran the Else case is chosen whether the user got the number right or not. Please help I have read over it so many times that it hurts.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'This script is designed to create a random number, and have a user guess the number
'If the user guesses the number incorrectly, negatively impact the users system
'if the user guess the number correctly, do nothing

dim InputValue
dim UserInput
'create a random number
dim r
randomize
r = int(rnd * 10)+1

'Allow the user to guess what number is correct
Input = inputbox ("Choose a number from one to ten, and choose wisely ;)", "Type a number.")
InputValue = Input
'Provide the user with feedback as to what his/her choice was and what the number actually was.
UserInput = "You typed " & InputValue & "." & " The number was " & r & "."
'echo the random generated number for test purposes
WScript.Echo r




Select Case InputValue
    Case r
        WScript.Echo "No action"
    Case Else
        WScript.Echo "Negative Action"
End Select
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `InputValue` is a `String` type because that's what's returned by the `InputBox` function and `r` is an `Integer`, so when you compare `InputValue` to `r`, you're comparing a string to an integer, i.e. apples to oranges.

Proof of concept:

```
Dim x
x = "5"

Dim y
y = 5

Select Case x
    Case y
        MsgBox "Yes" 
    Case Else
        MsgBox "No" 'this is what happens.
End select
```

VBScript is not a strongly-typed language, i.e. it does not know about types really at all -- well, it kind of knows.  It treats every variable as one type called a "variant" which itself can then have an affinity to a more specific type but in a very confusing and error-prone way.  I'd say you should [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to learn more about it.

You can get into a lot of trouble with this unless you always make sure you know what "types" you're working with.

Try changing it to this:

```
InputValue = CInt(Input)
```

Now you're converting the "string" into an "integer" (the variables are both still actually "variants" but they have the same underlying affinity to integer).  However, you want to be careful because someone might input a value that is *not* able to be converted to an integer, e.g. `hello`, and thus you'll get an error on this line.  You will need to do some error checking first before converting it.

Comment: Quick check is all you need `If Len(Input & "") > 0 And IsNumeric(Input & "") Then Input = CLng(input) Else input = 0`

Comment: I deleted the comment where I pointed out that `select case "5": case 5: msgbox "yes":  end select` is `yes` because as you say the variables are both variants with different types whereas the constant literals presumably get different treatment,